# In C# How to call Set method without a value

Tags: c#, getter-setter

I have a property and a set method that do something, I want to call that set method but without a value, How can I do that?

For example for the following property with set method:

```
private int myNum;
public String MyNumber
{
    get { return myNum };
    set {
          Randon rnd = new Random();
          myNum = rnd.Next(1,13);
        }
}
```

Comment: _MyNumber = null;_ but really this is not what properties are built for. You should have a method for that

Comment: Your code doesn't even compile!

Comment: What would be the point of calling the set method without a value? Why use the set method for that? Why not just write a regular method that does that, and let the set method work normally?

Comment: Are you aware that your getter must return a string, not an integer? However you provide an int as return-value, which can´t be converted to string.

Answer (score 2):

You can set its value inside the constructor of you your class itself, and then include rest of your properties, you can add extra logic on initialization as well for any other read-only property.

```
public class YourClass
{ 
    public YourClass()
    {
        _rnd = new Random();
        _myNum = rnd.Next(1,13);
    }
    private Random _rnd
    private int _myNum;
    public String MyNumber
    {
        get { return _myNum };
        private set;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're ignoring the `value` anyway, so you can call it with any value. However, this goes against any expectation you can reasonably have while calling a setter.

So put that logic into a method that describes its intent:

```
public int MyNumber { get; private set; }

public void SetRandomNumber()
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    MyNumber = rnd.Next(1,13);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just extract a method from your setter and call that:

```
private int myNum;
public int MyNumber
{
    get { return myNum; }
    set { DoSomething(); }
}

public void DoSomething()
{
    Randon rnd = new Random();
    myNum = rnd.Next(1,13);
}
```

However it´s strange not to use the value within a setter at all. That makes me think you shouldn´t even have a setter:

```
private int myNum;
public String MyNumber { get { return myNum; } }
```

A setter is actually nothing but a method that expects a `value` as parameter, similar to this:

```
public void Set_MyNumber(string value) { this.myNum = value; }
```

This is why *not* providing a `value` isn´t possible.

Comment: Now you still have a setter that ignores `value`, which is counter-intuitive.

Comment: @CodeCaster OP has this anyway, I agree it´s weird, but that´s obviously what OP wants.

Comment: Then fix what OP has instead of leaving such a weird implementation. No need for the `set`.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile btw.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I guess it should now.

Answer (score -1):

Try this,
Set called when you try to set value

```
MyNumber = "" ;
```